# Can an object style inherit width and height in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, object-styles

I'm making a a bunch of object styles for specifically sized rounded rectangles. I created the first style, set the width, height, the stroke style, corners and the fill transparency.

Then created several more styles based on that first style the only difference is the colour of the fill and stroke.

I can adjust all the parameters in the first style that update to the child styles, the only thing that does not come through is width and height and that is the most important one.

Is there a way to make this work?

Using Adobe Indesign CC latest.